# A lot of errors after migrate project from VS2015 to VS2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, migration, visual-studio-2017

I have ASP .NET CORE project in Visual Studio 2015.
Additonally I have StyleCop in whole solution.
After migration to Visual Studio 2017 (I just used one-way migration from VS2017) I have a lot of errors (over 3000) like:

- `Using directive must appear within a namespace declaration`
- `Tabs and spaces should be used correctly`
- `Prefix local calls with this`
- `Elements must be documented`

What's more - with this same settins - all works on VS2015.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: I'd start afresh and copy source files to vs2017 project then set up csproj file yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all stylecop rules. You can use ruleset files to force stylecop to ignore some of those rules. Alternatively you can click on one of the offending lines of code, hit `control + .` and apply the refactor across your entire solution (there should be an option to 'fix' the problem across the solution).

You can see how rules can be managed with this file: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers.ruleset#L76

You can reference rules files in your csproj with these angle brackets

`<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\path\to\Stylecop.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>`

You can mark rules as Error, Warning, Hide, or None. Most people use None to completely force a rule to be ignored.

You can see the docs on ruleset files here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264949.aspx